# Replace find_by_sql with a regular query

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this query:

```
tag_names = Tag.find_by_sql "SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(' ', name) FROM tags WHERE id IN (#{tag_ids.join(',')}) AND tag_type = 'Communication_Ways'"
```

Is there a way to do it in rails with: Tag.find(:all, ???)

The problem is that this query does not return anything because GROUP_CONCAT returns a string and not a Tag model.

Comment: are you trying to get all the tag names joined by `,` from the query?

Answer (score 0):

can you please try this :

You can use `calculate` method to do `GROUP_CONCAT` : http://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-calculate

```
Tag.select(:name).where(:id => tag_ids, :tag_type => 'Communication_Ways').calculate(:group_concat, "name separator ' '")
```

#### Update For Rails 2.3.8

calculate method in Rails 2.3.8 : http://api.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations/ClassMethods.html#M001705

```
Tag.find(:all, :select => 'name', :conditions => ["id IN (?) AND tag_type = (?)", tag_ids.join(', '), 'Communication_Ways']).calculate(:group_concat, "name separator ' '")
```

Comment: No, I get an ERROR: undefined method `calculate' for []:Array

Answer (score 0):

If tag_ids is an array, I would try:

```
tag_names = Tag.find(:tag_id = tags_ids).map(&:name).uniq.join(',')
```

Rails will translate an array of `[tag_ids]` into the `IN` statement.

You might have to fiddle the syntax a little for `2.3.8`, I use rails 3 and 4.